# React: setState value not working when refreshing the web

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have created the `a` variable within the `app.js` constructor of my App and I am getting crazy to update its value.

```js
this.state = {
    a: "1"
}
```

Originally I created a function `AddA()` to update its value when a button is clicked:

```js
async addA(){
    this.a=2;
};
```

But i realized that `setState` was asynchronous, so when I refreshed the page, the showed value is the original one defined on its initialization, so I update the logic of my function as follows:

```js
AddA = () => {    
   this.setState({
      a: 2
   })
}
```

But I do not why, for any reason my compiler says that the defined syntax is wrong:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The state value initialization happens, when the page gets mounted. As long as the component stays mounted, you can manipulate the `state` values. `onRefresh` the page will be `unmounted` and `mount` again, thus the older state will no longer remains and `re-initialization` happens.

if you really want those data to be persisted, please kindly use `redux-persisted store` or keep your data in `cookie` or `server - which is advisible.`

Answer (score 0):

When ever you refresh you page, the state will be reset to its intial value as the page will be remounted and the constructor will be called. So, to keep the data stored, you can use the following tools:

1. Persisted Store
2. Localstorage
3. Cookie
4. Database

You can use any of them according to your useCase.

**Regarding the error you are getting:**

Change you **AddA** function from:

```
AddA = () => {

  this.setState({
    a: 2
  })
}
```

to

```
const AddA = () => {

  this.setState({
    a: 2
  })
}
```

or

```
function AddA() {
    
      this.setState({
        a: 2
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating data on the client side then you can use localstorage.
[Here is a site that demonstrates how to do it](https://code-maven.com/on-load-counter-with-javascript-and-local-storage)